# How to design API to be used by untrusted 3rd party

Tags: web-services, rest, api-design

### Background

I need to design a WebService REST API. This web service will be consumed from a Web page and some mobile apps (android and iOS). I will call all of them 'apps'. Apps will be developed by third parties, outside of our company. Mobile Apps requires a logged in user to display content, so it's easier for me to handle content authorization of my web service.

Web page is a bit tricky because it must provide some functionality even for non logged users, (eg: list latests products, display product details and search products), so even to non-logged in users:

- It must be able to request some data (mostly /products and /products/{id} ) from my web service.
- It must be able to consume /search endpoint.

### Real question

I will use OAuth2 to handle authorization. On mobile apps this is not a problem, they will not be able to access any content until they get authorized, so once authorized all API will be working.

But I'm totally lost on how to handle connection with web app.

- Should I leave some URL non-authorized to allow web dispatch content to non logged in users?
- Should I create a special user 'anonimous' with higher API usage rate limits and tell Web app to authorize as 'anonimous' until user has been logged in ?